# Facebook Pixel doesn't work on mobile browser (but works on desktop browser)

Tags: wordpress, facebook, pixel, facebook-pixel

I'm implementing Facebook Pixel on my WordPress website. Everything works fine on the desktop. The pixel is activated is and working fine.

- I installed the Facebook Pixel Helper plug in for Chrome, and it detects the pixel on my page
- I test the events by opening my website on desktop browser, the page view event is detected on the dashboard. The pixel can also detect other events I set, like contact, content view, etc. All works fine.

Problem: when I open my website from mobile browser (I tried mobile Chrome, Kiwi Browser, Samsung Browser), the dashboard didn't detect the page view event, as well as other events. I tried to open from another mobile phones, same result. I tried to deactivate all my WordPress plug-in to check if one of them is conflicting, but still same result. I inspected my website from mobile browser, it has the Facebook pixel script on the header part, just like on desktop browser, so it should be working fine.

Anyone knows the solution? I don't know what causes this problem. I use Hestia theme and Elementor for my WordPress website.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps:

**1 °** Mobile usually has cache (I don't think so), but try to clear the caches and try again.

**2 °** If there are cache plugins please clear all caches please (I don't think so)

**3 °** Some themes are available in several headers and some of them are different for mobile and desktop, check if the headers are different and insert the tag manually if necessary in each header.

**4 °** To check if everything is ok, with google chrome if you press f12 you have the option to choose a device for testing. Choose an Android or IOS phone from the emulators and reload the screen to test. In cell phones can be false / positive information received sometimes.

Try these options and update your question with new information to try to help you.

Comment: Hi Kelvin, thank you very much for your feedback.

I tried the steps you suggested:

1 & 2. Events from mobile phone still not detected.

3. I'm new to Wordpress and my knowledge about CSS is very limited, could you please tell me how to know which header the theme uses for mobile, and which header for desktop? And how to insert the tag manually to the header for mobile?
What I know is: from WP-admin select Appearance > Theme Editor, then open header.php.

Comment: I also checked and compared the header for desktop and the header for mobile using the view source. The only difference I could find were these lines of codes, which were available on desktop but not available on mobile. :

<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'
<link rel='stylesheet' id='elementor-icons-css' 
<link rel='stylesheet' id='elementor-common-css'

Comment: 4. I tried your suggestion with this steps: From desktop I opened my website > press F12 > I choose Galaxy S5 > press F5. The event page view was detected on the dashboard. I also tried iPhone X, and the event was also detected.

Please let me know if there is any other info I should provide.
Thank you.

Comment: If in the preview everything is ok, using the emulator then it should be working on the phone.
How are you doing to test on your phone and know it isn't working? could you provide the site url so i can check here?